# How can we concatenate multiple strings together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a string that looks like this.

```
my_string = ''.join('place_id': 'x', 'licence': 'x', 'osm_type': 'X', 'osm_id': 'X', 'boundingbox': 'X', 'lat': 'X', 'lon': 'X')
```

Or, this:

```
my_string = str('place_id': 'x', 'licence': 'x', 'osm_type': 'X', 'osm_id': 'X', 'boundingbox': 'X', 'lat': 'X', 'lon': 'X')
```

I keep getting errors about invalid syntax. I think it's the `:` character that's causing the issue, but I don't know. Can someone point out my mistake, because I'm not seeing it.

My expected result is a string with this:

```
'place_id': 231350287, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 701902497, 'boundingbox': ['41.4689704', '41.4693896', '-81.9377844', '-81.9371249'], 'lat': '41.46913635', 'lon': '-81.93749898507869'
```

Comment: what do you mean ? to concatenate the `X`s or the keywords like `place_id` ... ?

Comment: What are you expecting as the result?  You're not concatenating strings there, you're trying to concatenate a dictionary, which doesn't work.  Are you trying to create JSON?

Comment: Did you mean: `my_string = str({'place_id': 'x', ... })`?

Comment: it isn't a dictionary tho, but if that was the case, then `''.join(my_dict.values())` or `''.join(my_dict.keys())` may do it

Comment: @TimRoberts: sure you can, it joins the keys. The problem is the dict expression syntax (@quamrana's comment that just came in)

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: My expected result is this: 'place_id': 231350287,
  'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
  'osm_type': 'way',
  'osm_id': 701902497,
  'boundingbox': ['41.4689704', '41.4693896', '-81.9377844', '-81.9371249'],
  'lat': '41.46913635',
  'lon': '-81.93749898507869'

Comment: Please edit your question to include that rather than as a comment

Comment: I'm using geolocator.geocode and sometimes it can't find some addresses. I want a placeholder for these non-found addresses. This string that I'm trying to create will be this place holder.

Comment: Once again, [edit] your question to clarify your problem

Comment: This worked for me:
my_string = {'place_id': 'x', 'licence': 'x', 'osm_type': 'X', 'osm_id': 'X', 'boundingbox': 'X', 'lat': 'X', 'lon': 'X'}
That's it. Sorry if I didn't explain things more clearly. I don't know how some of these things work. I majored in finance in school. I read several Python books a few years ago and I mess around with code samples all the time. That's how I learned whatever I learned.

Comment: Just so you know, you have created a ‘dict’. This is quite a normal thing in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't put `:` directly inside `join`

I suggest you to do something like this :

```
my_string = ', '.join(['place_id'+': '+'x', 'licence'+': '+'x', 'osm_type'+': '+'X', 'osm_id'+': '+'X', 'boundingbox'+': '+'X', 'lat'+': '+'X', 'lon'+': '+'X'])
```

or this :

```
my_string = ', '.join(['place_id: ' + 'x', 'licence: ' + 'x', 'osm_type: ' + 'X', 'osm_id: ' + 'X', 'boundingbox: ' + 'X', 'lat: ' + 'X', 'lon: ' + 'X'])
```

quite ugly but should work

Comment: This isn't concatenation, though. I assume OP has dynamic data, otherwise there'd already be a string to begin with, not key value pairs

Comment: I got it working. All set now. Thanks for trying to help! appreciate it!!